# Put string from external file into variable as print function would print it in console

Tags: python, string, file-io

Is there a safe way to "print" string into variable?
After processing text files I have my result that can contain `"'some text.'"` or `"'some other \\\ntext'"`. That's because I look into some python files that contain e.g.

example.py:

```
a = 'some text.'
b = 'some other \
text'
```

I'd like to have something like output of print, my result should look like:

```
'some text.'
'some other text'
```

I know that I can use something like:

```
a = "'some other \\\ntext'" 
#remember that a is string that I've read from other file. 
#It's here only to show you how looks it's representation in memmory
exec('result = ' + a)
#so result is 'some other text' as it would be in variable in other file.
```

But that seems vulnerable for me. Using just `str()` doesn't work. Is there better way to do that?

**[EDIT]**
To be more specific example below:

a.py:

```
b ='some other \
text'
```

main.py:

```
with open('a.py') as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
result = re.search('b\s=.+\n*.*', fileContent)
result = result.group(0) #now I have 'b = "some other\\\ntext"' in result
result = result[result.find('=')+1:] #now I have '"some other \\\ntext"'
```

But I'd like to have 'some other text' in my result, as I'd have in variable b in file a.py!

Comment: You text will work fine as is.

Comment: If it had I'd have known it. In memory I have e.g. `a` represented as `"'some other \\\ntext'"` (look at quotation marks carefully), so that's not what I want. I want to have 'some other text' as I have in file I parsed, but in that particular file it was done in this way: 
`'some other \(newline)
text'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `repr()`:

```
a = 'some text.'
result = repr(a)
print result
```

gives

```
'some text.'
```

(which means `result` now contains the string including the quotes).

Comment: That's function that I need in negative - as you wrote your code gives `'some text.'` but you store `'\'some text.\'' in memory. I have "'some text.'" in memory, while I'd like to have 'some text.' .

Comment: Write a unit test which shows us what you want to achieve. Are you aware that single and double quotes in Python mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes I am. But I have <double quote> <single quote> some text <single quote> <double quote>, and that's not the same as only string, I'd say that's string inside string (because of parsing file in which I look for string). I'd consider it done, topic is really duplicate as it's marked. ast.literal_eval solves my problem.